# model item passed into dictionary is of type 'system.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]',but dictionary is model B

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, combobox

I am trying to create a create combobox with performcallback, but I got the error. here this error "***the model item passed into dictionary is of type 'system.Collections.Generic.Lost'1[System.String]', but this dix=ctionary requires a model item of type 'DIS_iDealer.Models.SalesMonitoringModel'***"

I don't know which code exactly I need to paste but this is what I have:
view combobox :

```
@model  DIS_iDealer.Models.SalesMonitoringModel

@Html.DevExpress().ComboBoxFor(m => m.mpmGroupLine.DESCRIPTION, settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "Desc_ID_CB";
    settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
    settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "cbPartialCategoryDetail" };
    settings.Properties.CallbackPageSize = 50;
    settings.Properties.ValueField = "DESCRIPTION";
    settings.Properties.TextField = "DESCRIPTION";
    settings.Width = 150;
    settings.SelectedIndex = 0;

    settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "function(s,e){e.customArgs['group_Id'] = Category_Id_CB.GetValue()}";
    settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorTextPosition = ErrorTextPosition.Right;
    settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
    settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;

}).BindList((List<string>)new DIS_iDealer.DataAccess.SalesMonitoringDAC().GetProductGroupDetail(Model.mpmGroupLine.GROUPID).ToList()).GetHtml()
```

controller :

```
namespace DIS_iDealer.Controllers
{
    public class ReportController : BaseController
    {

[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Report_SalesMonitoring_2()
        {
            SalesMonitoringModel mode = new SalesMonitoringModel();
            //MPMPRODUCTGROUPLINE itemB = new MPMPRODUCTGROUPLINE();
            /*List<string> mpmCate = mode.GetProductGroup();
            if (mpmCate != null)
            {
                itemB.DESCRIPTION = mode.mpmGroupLine.DESCRIPTION;
            }*/
            ReportModels modelReport = new ReportModels();
            if (TempData["ReportSalesMonitoring2"] != null)
            {
                modelReport = (ReportModels)TempData["ReportSalesMonitoring2"];
                string reportParam = string.Empty;
                foreach (string item in modelReport.ParameterReport)
                {
                    reportParam += item;
                }
                ViewBag.IframeURL = modelReport.WebURL + reportParam;
            }
            return View(mode);
        }

[ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult cbPartialCategoryDetail(string group_Id)
        {
            //SalesMonitoringModel model = new SalesMonitoringModel();
            SalesMonitoringDAC model = new SalesMonitoringDAC();
            List<string> itemDetail = model.GetProductGroupDetail(group_Id);

            return PartialView("_cbPartialCategoryDetail", itemDetail);
        }
}
}
```

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: What is the model in your `_cbPartialCategoryDetail.cshtml` view? - it should be `@model List<string>` (not `@model SalesMonitoringDAC`)

Comment: I use @model SalesMonitoringDAC to get GROUPID combobox

Comment: But your `cbPartialCategoryDetail(string group_Id)` method is returning `List<string>`, not `SalesMonitoringDAC` (hence the exception). What you return in the controller must match the model you have defined in the view. One or the other needs to change

Comment: I already changed the method with List<SalesMonitoringModel> same with the return value in controller. but I still get following error

Comment: Changing the return type to `List<SalesMonitoringModel>` wont work. The model in you view is defined as `@model SalesMonitoringModel` (not `List<SalesMonitoringModel>` Read my last comment - they need to match!

Comment: can you give me example? I don't know what must I do, because I have just started to learn MVC 4

Comment: In order to make the error go away, your `cbPartialCategoryDetail()` method needs to be `return PartialView("_cbPartialCategoryDetail", model);` (but you don't appear to be initializing `model` with any values - its just a default new instance - so its not clear how that would affect other code you have)

Comment: it's work, but the items in the combobox not out. I use this combobox to display the details of one of the other combox if selected. I use performcallback